# Implementing a multiplexer for a given function

Tags: multiplexer, boolean-algebra

I am a Little bit stuck here. Lets say we have the function $$Y=BC+\overline { A } \overline { B } \overline { C } +B\overline { C } $$

How can I can implement this function with just a 4:1 multiplexer?

Comment: You can't.  the MUX has three inputs and if they are all low the output will also be low.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: draw up the truth table and think about the multiplexer as a look up table. I.e. choose two of the inputs (A,B,C) to act as the select inputs of the multiplexer, it doesn't matter which ones. Then basically we just have to look at how the output depends on the third input.

Say we select A and B to be the multiplexer control inputs. For each of the four possible combinations of A and B they will select a different input, or 'look up' the output value. Now you just have to look at how the output depends on C.

So for example when A and B are both zero the first input will be routed to the output. For the logic function you gave, the output will be 1 if C is 0 and 0 if C is 1. Basically this means the first mux input should be connected to NOT C as this will produce the desired output.

Similarly, for A=0, B=1 the second input is selected. In the case of the logic function you gave, the output is always 1 regardless of the value of C so the second mux input should be just connected to a high voltage.

You can continue with this process to determine what the other inputs should be connected to.

To summarise the procedure is:

-Choose two inputs to control the mux

-For each of the four control input combinations, look how the output depends on the third input. The only possibilities here are C, !C, always 1 or always 0.

-Connect the appropriate mux input up to the appropriate possibility.

This may be somewhat unclear without a logic diagram, but I have left that out intentionally so you can work through it. It is a rewarding process.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this. But the easiest to discuss here are "exhaustive" after a fashion. Start with your equation and expand it so that all the terms show:

$$\begin{align*}
Y&= B\: C + \overline{A}\: \overline{B}\: \overline{C} +B\: \overline{C}\\\\
 &=A\: B\: C +\overline{A}\: B\: C+ \overline{A}\: \overline{B}\: \overline{C} +B\: \overline{C}\\\\
 &=A\: B\: C +\overline{A}\: B\: C+ \overline{A}\: \overline{B}\: \overline{C} +A\:B\: \overline{C} +\overline{A}\:B\: \overline{C}
\end{align*}$$

The above transitions should be no problem for you to understand. I just expanded a couple of terms to use both possible states of \$A\$.

---

Now just list this out using all possible combinations (not permutations) of the three inputs as the first two factors in each term:

$$\begin{align*}
Y&=\bigg[\:\overline{A}\: \overline{B}\:\bigg]\: \overline{C} +\bigg[\:\overline{A}\:B\:\bigg]\bigg[\: \overline{C}+C\:\bigg] + \bigg[\:A\: B\:\bigg]\bigg[\: \overline{C}+C\:\bigg]\tag{AB}\label{AB}\\\\
&=\bigg[\:\overline{A}\: \overline{C}\:\bigg]\bigg[\: \overline{B}+B\:\bigg]  +\bigg[\:\overline{A}\: C\:\bigg] B+ \bigg[\:A\: \overline{C}\:\bigg]B+\bigg[A\: C\:\bigg]\: B\tag{AC}\label{AC}\\\\
&=\bigg[\:\overline{B}\: \overline{C}\:\bigg]\overline{A}+ \bigg[\:B\: \overline{C}\:\bigg]\bigg[\:\overline{A}+A\:\bigg]  +\bigg[\:B\: C\:\bigg]\bigg[\:\overline{A}+A\:\bigg]\tag{BC}\label{BC}
\end{align*}$$

Looking over \$\ref{AB}\$ above, you can see that \$\overline{C}\$ will be required for one of the terms. Since this requires a logic gate you aren't permitted, that option is excluded.

Looking over \$\ref{AC}\$ above, you can see that \$1\$ and \$B\$ will be required. These are both trivially available to you. So this option may be worth considering.

Looking over \$\ref{BC}\$ above, you can see that \$\overline{A}\$ will be required for one of the terms. Since this requires a logic gate you aren't permitted, that option is excluded.

---

It should be pretty obvious how to arrange things, now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That means I have to use A and C as selectors. But there are still 5 minterms. And ¬A¬C has to possible options.

Comment: @ofr13 No. If you can read the logic there, you can easily see that each of the four inputs to the multiplexor are perfectly determined.

Comment: @ofr13 Do you see that \$\overline{B}+B = 1\$?